# How to do the margins for same exact spacing?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to do the margins either in CSS or Bootstrap so that there is the same exact spacing/margins between each card.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($properties as $property):?>
      <div class="card col-md-4 text-center py-4 px-3 mb-4">
        <img src="<?php echo $property->logo; ?>" class="logo__style" /><br />
        <h4><?php echo $property->title; ?></h4><br />
        <a href="<?php echo $property->registration_url; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">View Event</a>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your card between the col
like this following code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($properties as $property):?>
      <div class=“col-md-4 text-center”>
       <div class=“card py-4 px-3”>
        <img src="<?php echo $property->logo; ?>" class="logo__style" /><br />
        <h4><?php echo $property->title; ?></h4><br />
        <a href="<?php echo $property->registration_url; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">View Event</a>
         </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Example

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row g-5">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card text-center py-4 px-3">
        <h4>Title goes here</h4>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View Event</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card text-center py-4 px-3">
          <h4>Title goes here</h4>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View Event</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card text-center py-4 px-3">
          <h4>Title goes here</h4>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View Event</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card text-center py-4 px-3">
          <h4>Title goes here</h4>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View Event</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card text-center py-4 px-3">
          <h4>Title goes here</h4>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View Event</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have modified my answer. Could you go over the answer again? And As you can see I have attached a code that will show you the output